# Extend IO pins to 256?

Tags: gpio

I could use a 16 bit io expander on the i2c bus but they only support 8 different slave addresses only giving me 128 io pins. I need at least 256 and more would be better. Any thoughts on how to best do this?

Comment: Which pi?  There's actually a second 12c bus available, but the means of accessing it is different on the A+/B+ than the A/B.

Comment: some detail on which io expanders you looked at would be useful.

Comment: More gpios for what purpose?  If they are just going to be used as slow moving inputs/outputs then it may not matter.  If you want to generate PWM/Servo signals, read sensors like the DHT22 etc. it very much does matter.

Answer (score 1):

I know the MCP23S17 will give you 16 GPIO pins via an SPI interface. It could be worth looking into. I'm no electrical engineer, but you could probably use an MCP23017 (I2C) to select which of 16 MCP23S17's (SPI) are active, giving you 256 GPIO pins.

Answer (score 0):

The 8 of the MCP23017 Chips would be half of it. 
You could use the PCF8574 i2c chip. It gives you another 8 with 16 IO each.
http://electronicsbyexamples.blogspot.com/2014/06/io-expander-pcf8574-with-raspberry-pi.html